# What's the meaning of "get hyped"?

Tags: meaning

I've come across with the sentence below:

> People often think it’s weird to get hyped about reading one page or
>   meditating for one minute or making one sales call.

Could you please tell me what the meaning of "get hyped" is?

The full text is:

> The most effective way I know to counteract this tendency is to use the
>   Two-Minute Rule, which states, “When you start a new habit, it should
>   take less than two minutes to do.” You’ll find that nearly any habit
>   can be scaled down into a two-minute version: “Read before bed each
>   night” becomes “Read one page.”
>   [...]
>   You can usually figure out the gateway habits that will lead to your
>   desired outcome by mapping out your goals on a scale from “very easy”
>   to “very hard.” For instance, running a marathon is very hard. Running
>   a 5K is hard. Walking ten thousand steps is moderately difficult.
>   Walking ten minutes is easy. And putting on your running shoes is very
>   easy. Your goal might be to run a marathon, but your gateway habit is
>   to put on your running shoes. That’s how you follow the Two-Minute
>   Rule
>   [...] **People often think it’s weird to get hyped about** reading one
>   page or meditating for one minute or making one sales call. But the
>   point is not to do one thing. The point is to master the habit of
>   showing up. The truth is, a habit must be established before it can be
>   improved. If you can’t learn the basic skill of showing up, then you
>   have little hope of mastering the finer details. Instead of trying to
>   engineer a perfect habit from the start, do the easy thing on a more
>   consistent basis. You have to standardize before you can optimize.

*Atomic Habits* by James Clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[(get) hyped](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hyped)** (v) (slang): 1. Extremely excited, ecstatic, stoked, treed, pumped, psyched, jazzed, amped, revved, wired.

It's possible that the original meaning was related to injecting yourself (using a *hypodermic needle*) with some kind of amphetamine, but now the slang is so old that any stigma is lost.  You can use it comfortably in casual conversation -- although I can't guarantee the younger generation won't consider it "old people's slang".

Just replace "get hyped" with "get excited" and the meaning of the phrase should become apparent.

> People often think it’s weird to **get excited** about [something]